# Advanced image color algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

Here are some examples of **selective color change** (from Wikipedia):

[image: x]

[image: x]

I've tried to find any information, papers or library code that do something like this. Does anyone know about this algorithm or where can I find some information about this? Something close to this algorithm would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea would be to detect an area to affect by color, and only apply the colorization effect to the pixels inside that area. This could be done by matching a range of RGB values, using HSL or HSV color space and matching on a range of hues, or other variations; you could also select any matching pixels anywhere in the image, or only the contiguous area of matching pixels that contains the originally selected pixel.

Comment: Thanks about your reply, I will make a research about it

Comment: Hey I did it, thaks a lot my friend